# Asp:RadioButtonList SelectedIndex not changing when set by javascript and then the buttons are disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have an asp:RadioButtonList with three choices where the second one is set to Selected = True and based on those three choices, javascript shows/hides parts of a table when they're chosen.


 
Usually this works fine, but in one instance, based on a dropdownlist choice, I set the chosen radiobutton to the first and then disables the radiobuttons because they can't choose anything else for that instance.

When I try to read the selectedIndex in code behind when they save, the selected change haven't been caught and it returns the second choice instead of the first.

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="CheckFaktura" Width="100%" runat="server" CellPadding="10" 
  CellSpacing="10" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow">
    <asp:ListItem>Privat</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Bedrift</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Fakturasentral</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

```
  if (ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value != "Er i jobb") {
            document.getElementById("stilling").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("Innmeldingfirmanavn").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("Innmeldingorgnummer").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("Innmeldingfirmaadresse").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("Innmeldingfirmasted").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("stillingsgruppe").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("RequiredFieldValidatorFN1").enabled = false;
            document.getElementById("RequiredFieldValidatorON1").enabled = false;
            document.getElementById("RequiredFieldValidatorFA1").enabled = false;
            document.getElementById("RequiredFieldValidatorFP1").enabled = false;
            document.getElementById("RequiredFieldValidatorFS1").enabled = false;
            document.getElementById("CheckFaktura_0").checked = true;
            //document.getElementById("CheckFaktura").disabled = true;
            $("#CheckFaktura").find('input').prop('disabled', true);
            document.getElementById("rfvStillingsgruppe").enabled = false;
            ShowHideFaktAdresse();
```

I'm assuming it's the disable that messes everything up, but then I need another way to make sure the users can't choose another option.

edit: AutopostBack is not an option since it messes with other stuff on the page.

Comment: Does it work if you don't disable radio list?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know of another way to keep them from being able to click on the other radiobuttons

Comment: Try surrounding RadioButtonList with div and disable that div instead of each radio button input.

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work. It's almost like using disable removes any changes made before it's disabled. Or like it can't read the new value even though it's set before it's disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work by setting all the buttons except the one that has to be chosen to disabled.

Doesn't explain why it wouldn't work, but at least it's a possible way if others have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

make your dropdown list and the radiobuttons list AutoPostBack and do your work on code behind ,it will work ..

Comment: I can't use postback because it messes with other stuff on the page

Comment: When are you changing the selected index of the radiobuttonlist ?

Comment: Technically never? it has an onclick event that does the second part of the code in my original post, but when I use firebug to see what happens, the selected index never actually changes in the code even though it registers it. I've tried setting the checked = true from the second button to the first and visually it looks like it's happening, but when I try to read it in code behind, it's still set as the second button selected